# Processing file uploads before object is saved

Tags: django, django-models, django-file-upload

I've got a model like this:

```
class Talk(BaseModel):
  title        = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  mp3          = models.FileField(upload_to = u'talks/', max_length=200)
  seconds      = models.IntegerField(blank = True, null = True)
```

I want to validate before saving that the uploaded file is an MP3, like this:

```
def is_mp3(path_to_file):
  from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
  audio = MP3(path_to_file)
  return not audio.info.sketchy
```

Once I'm sure I've got an MP3, I want to save the length of the talk in the seconds attribute, like this:

```
audio = MP3(path_to_file)
self.seconds = audio.info.length
```

The problem is, before saving, the uploaded file doesn't have a path (see [this ticket](http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10788), closed as `wontfix`), so I can't process the MP3.

I'd like to raise a nice validation error so that `ModelForm`s can display a helpful error ("You idiot, you didn't upload an MP3" or something).

Any idea how I can go about accessing the file before it's saved?

<sup>p.s. If anyone knows a better way of validating files are MP3s I'm all ears - I also want to be able to mess around with ID3 data (set the artist, album, title and probably album art, so I need it to be processable by [mutagen](http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/)).</sup>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access the file data in [request.FILES](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) while in your view.

I think that best way is to [bind uploaded files to a form](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#binding-uploaded-files), override the forms [clean method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), get the [UploadedFile object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files) from cleaned_data, validate it anyway you like, then override the  [save method](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) and populate your models instance with information about the file and then save it.

Comment: +1 and accepted! This seems to be the way to go - seems kind of a shame that there's not an elegant way to do this using new-fangled model validation.

Comment: Maybe you could but it is quite new and i am not yet familiar enough with it.

Comment: Could you write an example?

Answer (score 1):

a cleaner way to get the file before be saved is like this:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

#this go in your class Model
def clean(self):
    try:
        f = self.mp3.file #the file in Memory
    except ValueError:
        raise ValidationError("A File is needed")
    f.__class__ #this prints <class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>
    processfile(f)
```

and if we need a path, ther answer is [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk)

Answer (score 0):

You could follow the technique used by [`ImageField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/forms/fields.py#L612) where it validates the file header and then seeks back to the start of the file.

```
class ImageField(FileField):
    # ...    
    def to_python(self, data):
        f = super(ImageField, self).to_python(data)
        # ...
        # We need to get a file object for Pillow. We might have a path or we might
        # have to read the data into memory.
        if hasattr(data, 'temporary_file_path'):
            file = data.temporary_file_path()
        else:
            if hasattr(data, 'read'):
                file = BytesIO(data.read())
            else:
                file = BytesIO(data['content'])

        try:
            # ...
        except Exception:
            # Pillow doesn't recognize it as an image.
            six.reraise(ValidationError, ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['invalid_image'],
                code='invalid_image',
            ), sys.exc_info()[2])
        if hasattr(f, 'seek') and callable(f.seek):
            f.seek(0)
        return f
```