# How to copy InMemoryUploadedFile object to disk

Tags: python, django, file-upload, file-storage

I am trying to catch a file sent with form and perform some operations on it before it will be saved. So I need to create a copy of this file in temp directory, but I don't know how to reach it. Shutil's functions fail to copy this file, since there is no path to it. So is there a way to do this operation in some other way ?

My code :

```
    image = form.cleaned_data['image']
    temp = os.path.join(settings.PROJECT_PATH, 'tmp')
    sourceFile = image.name # without .name here it wasn't working either
    import shutil
    shutil.copy(sourceFile, temp)
```

Which raises :

`Exception Type: IOError at /

Exception Value: (2, 'No such file or directory')`

And the debug :

```
#  (..)\views.py in function

  67. sourceFile = image.name
  68. import shutil
  69. shutil.copy2(sourceFile, temp) ...

# (..)\Python26\lib\shutil.py in copy2

  92. """Copy data and all stat info ("cp -p src dst").
  93.
  94. The destination may be a directory.
  95.
  96. """
  97. if os.path.isdir(dst):
  98. dst = os.path.join(dst, os.path.basename(src))  
  99. copyfile(src, dst) ... 
 100. copystat(src, dst)
 101.

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
dst     
u'(..)\\tmp\\myfile.JPG'
src     
u'myfile.JPG'
# (..)\Python26\lib\shutil.py in copyfile

  45. """Copy data from src to dst"""
  46. if _samefile(src, dst):
  47. raise Error, "`%s` and `%s` are the same file" % (src, dst)
  48.
  49. fsrc = None
  50. fdst = None
  51. try:
  52. fsrc = open(src, 'rb') ...
  53. fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
  54. copyfileobj(fsrc, fdst)
  55. finally:
  56. if fdst:
  57. fdst.close()
  58. if fsrc:

▼ Local vars
Variable    Value
dst     
u'(..)\\tmp\\myfile.JPG'
fdst    
None
fsrc    
None
src     
u'myfile.JPG'
```

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806586/reading-file-data-during-forms-clean-method/2806655#2806655) is similar question, it might help.

```
import os
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.conf import settings

data = request.FILES['image'] # or self.files['image'] in your form

path = default_storage.save('tmp/somename.mp3', ContentFile(data.read()))
tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
```

Comment: Hii, i think hardcoded the "tmp/name.mp3" it will be an issue in cross platform path, I try to improve your code
<pre>
from django.conf import settings

tmp = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, "tmp", data.name)
path = default_storage.save(tmp, ContentFile(data.read()))</pre>

Comment: issues start when u upload many MB in one file.
use buffering then. like data.read(BUF_SIZE) in while loop.

Comment: Many/large is a relative measure and has a number of variables (like, amount of memory, disk size, network type/speed etc), but yes for large files you would probably write to [disk in chunks](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: You can avoid hardcoding the name using: `FileField(upload_to='data-files-dir').generate_filename(None, data.name)`

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned by [@Sławomir Lenart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk?lq=1#comment40779691_3705098), when uploading large files, you don't want to clog up system memory with a `data.read()`.

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/) :

> Looping over `UploadedFile.chunks()` instead of using `read()` ensures
>   that large files don't overwhelm your system's memory

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage

filename = "whatever.xyz" # received file name
file_obj = request.data['file']

with default_storage.open('tmp/'+filename, 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in file_obj.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
```

This will save the file at `MEDIA_ROOT/tmp/` as your `default_storage` will unless told otherwise.

Comment: Like this I get: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<storage>/<path>/<my image name>.png'. Ideas?

Comment: @Daviddd the file is not where you think it is, and it's irrelevant to this code.

Comment: @Emile Bergeron I am using django_storages as.default_storage. How can I write a file to the media root ?

Answer (score 8):

Here is another way to do it with python's `mkstemp`:

```
### get the inmemory file
data = request.FILES.get('file') # get the file from the curl

### write the data to a temp file
tup = tempfile.mkstemp() # make a tmp file
f = os.fdopen(tup[0], 'w') # open the tmp file for writing
f.write(data.read()) # write the tmp file
f.close()

### return the path of the file
filepath = tup[1] # get the filepath
return filepath
```

Answer (score 5):

Your best course of action is to write a custom Upload handler. See the [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#writing-custom-upload-handlers) . If you add a "file_complete" handler, you can access the file's content regardless of having a memory file or a temp path file. You can also use the "receive_data_chunck" method and write your copy within it.

Regards

Comment: i was using this for a while until when a duplicate name is uploaded and django automatically appends a suffix to make the filename unique. That renamed filename was not available at the upload handler level. Other than that this worked very cleanly.

Answer (score 4):

This is how I tried to save the file locally

```
    file_object = request.FILES["document_file"]
    file_name = str(file_object)
    print(f'[INFO] File Name: {file_name}')
    with open(file_name, 'wb+') as f:
        for chunk in file_object.chunks():
            f.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `default_storage` (as mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705098/8283848)) is not a good option (at least to me!). I would rather use [**`FileSystemStorage`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage) directly.

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse


def simple_view(request):
    in_memory_file_obj = request.FILES["file"]
    FileSystemStorage(location="/tmp").save(in_memory_file_obj.name, in_memory_file_obj)
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

Notes:

- The `location` can be any value that suites for a directory path. It can even be a `/tmp`.
- Solution tested with `Django 4.1`