# Python - Upload a HTML File to GAE Django and print back using HttpResponse

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am using GAE with django.
I am trying to upload a HTML file to the server and the parse it in the server.
I Have the parser.
All I need is to be able to read it in the code.

Here's my code as of now:
The Views:

```
def upload_file(request):
    from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/file')
    t = os.path.abspath("templates/upload.html")
    return render(request,t,{'url':upload_url})

def file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
          # Get image data
          from app.models.models import Blobs
          b= Blobs()
          avatar = request.FILES['file'].read()
          name = request.POST['name']
          b.html = avatar
          b.name = name
          b.put()
          qry = Blobs.query(Blobs.name == name)
          file = qry.get()
          b.key.delete()
          return HttpResponse(avatar ,content_type="text/html")
```

my HTML form:

```
<html>

<body>
    <form action="{{url}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div>
            <textarea name="name" rows="3" cols="60"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Avatar:</label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="file" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="upload file">
        </div>
    </form>
    <hr>
    <form>name:
        <input value="%s" name="file_name"> {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="submit" value="switch">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

My Db:

```
class Blobs(ndb.Model):
    html = ndb.BlobProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

And the browser output:

> Content-Type: text/html Content-Length: 502302 Content-MD5: OGViN2VhZWIzNTU1YTMzZjFlY2IwNTVjMWEzYjdmNzM= content-disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="FILE.html" X-AppEngine-Upload-Creation: 2015-09-25 15:49:32.054302

I can't seem to figure out what I'm missing here

Fixed it by using  ContentFile function  return HttpResponse(ContentFile(avatar),content_type="text/html")

Got my answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk)

Comment: This isn't even close to making sense. You have a field called "img" which you want to have HTML in. You upload something to the blobstore, then for no reason you create a new instance of your model and straight away delete it. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I know the name doesnt make sense. this is just because i have used an existing form. the deleting part is just because i dont want it to upload the file multiple times while testing

Comment: What @DanielRoseman said. What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need to upload the HTML file?

Comment: @MeLight I need to upload the HTML and then parse is in the server and use the parsed data

Comment: @Itamar So which part is not working, the upload, the parsing, or returning the answer?

Comment: @MeLight i have problem opening the file in the code and parsing it

Comment: Thanks. That same question is linked in the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by using  `ContentFile` function 
`return HttpResponse(ContentFile(avatar),content_type="text/html")`

Found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk)