# Django REST ImageField Serializer close file

Tags: python, django

I want to do bulk images `POST` to the server.
And the same image will be upload to multiple records in Django 1.11 and Django REST 3.6.1

```
for image in images:
   data = {
                'type': image_type,
                'attribute': {
                    'dealer_id': int(dealer_id),
                },
                'defaults': {
                    'created_user': user,
                    'updated_user': user,
                    'image': image,
                }
            }
   for shop_id in shops:
            DisplayImage.objects.update_or_create(**data)
```

First image does not raises the error. During debugging I had try query that `DisplayImage` instance, but it returns empty queryset. It is not a problem because ORM may be lazy-commit.

The error I have is `I/O Operation on closed file`

**Update:**
To keep attention from the community. I will keep adding information while I am working on this until I give up.

```
data == copy_data
Out[2]: False
data
Out[3]: 
{'attribute': {'dealer_id': 2},
 'created_user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>,
 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: コーティング_車内清掃_室内清掃+除菌抗菌消臭_内容.png (image/png)>,
 'type': 1,
 'updated_user': <SimpleLazyObject: <User: admin>>}
copy_data
Out[4]: 
{'attribute': {'dealer_id': 2},
 'created_user': <User: admin>,
 'image': <InMemoryUploadedFile: コーティング_車内清掃_室内清掃+除菌抗菌消臭_内容.png (image/png)>,
 'type': 1,
 'updated_user': <User: admin>}
```

I had tried `copy.deepcopy(data)` which is a `dict` that I want to create an instance of `DisplayImage`, but when the first one went to the database the next one got closed!
I am ware that it must be different object that is the reason why I check the value by `data == copy_data` and it returns `False`

Comment: It has same and only image to be saved for different data?

Comment: Yes yes yes. The same file save to different record.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I/O Operation on closed file. But first file is not raises an error. second file raises. This is first shop not the second shop.

Comment: I got the solution now. I have to save it to disk and then let Django read from disk and commit record to the database. Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk

Comment: thats  great.....