# Unable to open PDF file written by python

Tags: python-3.x, pdf, byte

In my Python code, I received a file as `InMemoryUploadedFile` and then I'm trying to save that file on disk. It says that file stored successfully but when I try to open that file, I get this error:

[image: File Opening Error]

Here is the code snippet that I'm trying with

```
with Path("check.pdf").open(mode="wb") as output_file:
    output_file.write(fileToParse.read())
```

Another code that I tried before is this one:

```
outfd, filePath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='check.pdf', dir=os.getcwd())
with open(filePath, "wb") as dest:
    dest.write(fileToParse)
os.close(outfd)
```

In both cases, I get same error. I've checked different posts and even on here SO, first solution is working for many people. But I don't know why it is not storing proper file for me.

The type of file `fileToParse` that I received is `<class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'>` and `fileToParse.read()` returns `<class 'bytes'>`

> Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: An example PDF file perhaps if you want people to help you figure out what is happening?

Comment: any kind of PDF file.. not working for anyone..

Comment: I don't write python and even if I did I wouldn't want to take the time to create a test file to see what happens. I _am_ however quite familiar with the PDF file format. I'm not the only person like that on here I'm sure. A test file in such a case - especially because it's apparently so easy to generate - doesn't strike me as an impossible thing to add to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue with the help of [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30195605/2660342) with minor changes. Here is the code that is working for me.

```
import tempfile, os

 outfd, filePath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix=fileToParse.name, dir=os.getcwd())
 with open(filePath, 'wb+') as destination:
    for chunk in fileToParse.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)    
 os.close(outfd)
```