# Save an InMemoryUploadedFile to OS in Django

Tags: django

I want to save a temporary uploaded file in the django `os`. How can I do that ?

The file is received as the following:

```
    file_obj = request.FILES['document']
```

I tried the following method but it saves the file in my AWS account but I just want to save it in the os and delete is as soon as I am done with it.

```
    file_name = default_storage.save(file_obj.name, file_obj)
    file_url = default_storage.url(file_name)
```

when I  pass the `file_url` in a function and try to read it I get the following error:

> OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
> 'https://xxxxxxxx.s3.amazonaws.com/media/Sample%20PFEP%20(2).xlsx'

I face no problem when I read the same file from local in my jupyter notebook. Why is that ?

Comment: os? you mean *local storage* ?

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Yes, I figured that once I save it I can read it in function more easily

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy InMemoryUploadedFile object to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk)

Comment: @ArakkalAbu   I tried ` tmp_file = os.path.join('pfep/', file_name)`  but the file was not save at that location

Comment: @ArakkalAbu Is there something as `os.save(request.Files['document']`?. I am unable to save the file from the above link

Comment: Why do you want to save the file? Because you are going to delete it after some process, right?