# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO' | Django | Pillow

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I have been working one a Django project and I need to save an image file manually. So, I tried using PIL. Here's the code in my Django view that breaks-

```
import PIL.Image as PilImage
image_file = request.FILES.get("pic").file
image = PilImage.open(io.BytesIO(image_file))
```

I don't understand it because io.BytesIO is a byte-like object, right? I couldn't find any solution anywhere so I'd appreciate any help.

The full error is below -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\venv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 98, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\App\utils\login_required.py", line 25, in wrapper
    return f(self, request, user_id)
  File "G:\Workspace\Rabo\App\views\user_views.py", line 125, in post
    image = PilImage.open(io.BytesIO(image_file))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'
```

EDIT: I used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705098/9545165) to save the image for now, but I'd still like to know why PIL gave the that error. I'd appreciate if someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't read the data from `io.BytesIO(image_file)`. `io.BytesIO(image_file).read()` should do the job

Comment: I did image = PilImage.open(io.BytesIO(image_file).read()) and it still shows the same error.