# Save uploaded InMemoryUploadedFile as tempfile to disk in Django

Tags: django, file, upload, storage

I'm saving a POST uploaded file to disk by using a technique described here:
[How to copy InMemoryUploadedFile object to disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3702465/how-to-copy-inmemoryuploadedfile-object-to-disk)

```
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.conf import settings

data = request.FILES['image']
path = default_storage.save('tmp/%s' % filename, ContentFile(data.read()))
tmp_file = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, path)
```

The file does get uploaded and stored at the specified location. However, the content is garbled. It's an image  - and when I look at the stored file, I see, the characters are not the same and the image file is damaged. The filesize, however, is the same as the original.

I guess, I need to do some conversion before saving the file, but how/which...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Highly recommend using the [**`FileSystemStorage`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.FileSystemStorage) directly instead of `default_storage` as the [`DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std-setting-DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE) can be set to another value.

```py
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.http import HttpResponse


def simple_view(request):
    in_memory_file_obj = request.FILES["file"]
    FileSystemStorage(location="/tmp").save(in_memory_file_obj.name, in_memory_file_obj)
    return HttpResponse("Success")
```

Note: Solution tested with `Django 4.1`

Comment: Thank you, worked for me! May be good to know: `FileSystemStorage` returns the actual name of the stored file. Because if a file with the original name already exists, Django will append some characters to the new filename to avoid the collision.